# Random Forest Classifier for Categorical Data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, random-forest

I have been using Random Forest Regression recently, and I'm getting awesome results.  I read online that you can use a Random Forest Classifier for categorical data, and I Googled for some examples of this, but I couldn't find anything that is very useful.  I saw a couple articles about one-hot encoding categorical data into numerical data, but as I know, that's not a great idea for the Random Forest methodology.  If you can actually use the Random Forest technique to predict outcomes based on categorical data, please share a few resources (links, code, etc.).  I'd love to test this concept.  I just can't seem to find a good tutorial on this topic.  I am working in a Python environment.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey ASH, read about CatBoost https://github.com/catboost/catboost, the algorithm handle categorical features very well and it's averaging great results for datasets with categorical data.

Comment: @FilipeLauar: RF works, XGboost is better, CatBoost might have better ease-of-use but seems gimmicky, and performance not any better - I have never seen anything showing that CatBoost outperforms RF or XGB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For regression and binary classification, decision trees (and therefore RF) implementations should be able to deal with categorical data. The idea is presented in the original paper of CART (1984), and says that it is possible to find the best split by considering the categories as ordered in terms of average response, and then treat them as such. You can find an explanation of the problem [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/splitting-categorical-predictors-for-multiclass-classification.html#btt1xp_) 
For multiclass classification, the problem is a bit more complicated.

Anyway, this method MIGHT lead to some overfitting, as you are actually using some Target Encoding (should not be too big of a problem for RF, maybe more for boosted machines). However, many implementations do not allow for automatic splitting on categorical variables, therefore it is good to know the best methods for encoding in trees. I suggest [this](https://medium.com/data-design/visiting-categorical-features-and-encoding-in-decision-trees-53400fa65931) medium article and [this](https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/) blog post.

Finally, some implementations deal differently and yet efficiently with categorical data. I suggest looking at [H2O's implementation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/nbins_cats.html), that uses a nice binning method for fast splitting.